# PHP MySQL sum dates range

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database structure like this:

```
id | start           | end             |
---+-----------------+-----------------+
1  |2016/01/01 10:00 |2016/01/10 09:45 |
---+-----------------+-----------------+
2  |2016/01/03 15:30 |2016/01/17 22:35 |
---+-----------------+-----------------+
3  |2016/01/12 17:15 |2016/01/20 11:20 |
...
```

I want to find a range of these two dates in days and sum all the days. Maybe anyone has a solution?

Comment: I've tried to find a difference in days to print it in rows' but I can't find a solution to sum it. I'm asking for solution, not for plain code dude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `select DATEDIFF(dateField1, dateField2) as dateInDays from yourTable`
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: so buddy, i suggest you to be clear in your question, in your question you mentioned "Mysql Sum datest" but it is actually finding range or difference between two date fields. Thanks & regards.

Comment: But now what i've got is "9 14 8 ", how to sum them in the same query?

Comment: If I write a query like this: "SELECT id, DATEDIFF(end, start) as day, SUM(day) as days", then I get 0 results...

Comment: SUM(DATEDIFF(dateField1, dateField2)) use this

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!